# Run jQuery for new DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can I run the jQuery script for new created DOM elements?
Look at the following code, if I click the class `.elem` it will run the code, but if I append new `.elem` the script won't run.

**JS:**

```
$('.elem').on('click', function(){
    $('.result').show().fadeOut('slow');
});
$('.add').on('click', function(){
    $('.block').append('<div class="elem">Element</div>');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="elem">Element</div>
    <div class="elem">Element</div>
    <div class="elem">Element</div>
</div>

<p><span class="add">Add new</span></p>

<div class="result">Result</div>
```

**JSFiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Y3Cn/3/

Any help is hightly appreciated. Thanks you;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) with any *static* parent element:

```
$('.block').on('click', '.elem', function() {
    $('.result').show().fadeOut('slow');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Y3Cn/4/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [event delegation](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events):

```
$('.block').on('click', '.elem', function(){
  $('.result').show().fadeOut('slow');
});
```